# dhcpd: How to tell how many leases are available?

Tags: dhcp-server

I'm a little bit new to dhcpd. I'm trying to figure out how many leases we have available on our network.

The `/var/lib/dhcpd/dhcpd.leases` file appears to show almost a history of leases and some of the current leases. Not sure if that really helps me or not...

I figured there might be a command or something I'm unaware of that can tell me how many leases are left.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need to parse the `dhcpd.leases` and `dhcpd.conf` files to get a picture of the metes and bounds of the available IP ranges and the state of each IP address within the address space.

The [DHCPStatus](http://dhcpstatus.sourceforge.net/dhcpstatus_summary.html) project might do what you need.